# Pass dropdown text to controller

Tags: model-view-controller

I have below dropdown, how do I retrieve the dropdown selected dropdown text (not value) on MVC controller upon clicking the submit button (httppost)?

```
<select id="detailThing" name="MyList">
<option value="BMI">ListDetail1</option>
<option value="BMI">ListDetail2</option>
<option value="BMI">ListDetail3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: is there a way to do it without changing the value? I need the value to stay as per original question...

Answer (score 0):

Put the `<select>` in a form and submit it to the controller. You will need a model with a string variable to pass the value into/through.

```
public class MyModel
{
    public String myValue { get; set; }
}
```

in the view put this line at the top;

```
@model MyProject.Models.MyModel
```

then create an html form and put your select inside and create a submit button;

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyControllerMethod", "MyController", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myform" }))
{
    <select id="detailThing" name="myValue">
        <option value="BMI">Putrajaya</option>
        <option value="BMI">Sepang</option>
        <option value="BMI">Hulu Langat</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

setting the 'name' of the select to `'myValue'` will link its 'selected' value to the variable on the model and pass it to the controller when the form is submitted. Hope this helps!

Update:

change the values to be the same as the display text,

```
<select id="detailThing" name="myValue">
     <option value="Putrajaya">Putrajaya</option>
     <option value="Sepang">Sepang</option>
     <option value="Hulu Langat">Hulu Langat</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Will it return the dropdown value or dropdown text? Because I need the dropdown text...

Comment: it will return the value not the visible text. Just alter the option value to be the same as the display text.

Comment: I'm following this code http://forums.asp.net/t/1989680.aspx?dropdown+items+filter+based+on+selection+of+another+dropdown+seleted+value+using+jquery, and now I have a dropdown that have same value but unique text. So, I need help on how to pass on dropdown text back to controller...